# Can I stop all comments on Facebook posts on a page I manage

Tags: facebook-pages

I am having issues with one person making inappropriate comments on a Facebook page I manage. I know I can ban/ block this person but feel we would get more repercussions. 
Can I stop everyone/anyone from commenting on posts.

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible , Facebook has no such option...